# json,CSV,json to csv

Tags: java, json, csv

I want to convert JSON into CSV. I have written the following code; it's working fine for a small JSON file, but for another file (around 43MB), it's not working.

```
public class JSON2CSV 
{

    public static void main(String myHelpers[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line="";
        int i=0;    
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tickets_1.txt"));   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {           
            i++;

            System.out.println("loop"+i);

            sb.append(line);


        }
            String resultstring =  sb.toString();

         String jsonString = "{\"infile\":"+resultstring+"}";

        JSONObject output;
        try {
            output = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("infile");
            File file=new File("fromTicketsJSON.csv");
            String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Is it java?

Comment: "its not working ... please help" – you'll have to try a bit harder for us to help you

Comment: is it `out of memory exception`? `sb.append(line);` certainly took pretty much memory.

Comment: Can you provide the sample json input?

Comment: [{"ticket_type":"Incident","to_emails":null,"requester_status_name":"This ticket has been Closed","display_id":44843,"responder_id":1000399659,"cc_email":{"reply_cc":[],"cc_emails":[],"fwd_emails":[],"tkt_cc":[]},"due_by":"2016-08-02T09:50:00+05:30","frDueBy":"2016-07-12T09:50:00+05:30","owner_id":null,"subject":"","created_at":"2016-07-05T17:45:46+05:30","fr_escalated":false,"description":"had joined to WS RETAIL on July 10, 2014 with the employee id of 531655. Later on September 1st 2014,

Comment: error is in this line  String csv = CDL.toString(docs);  error is string out of bound exception